# How can I collect information about the column of a row of an array?

Tags: javascript

I have an array encoded in json which within each array element I have columns which I cannot read from the traditional method . The end result is undefined, I understand that the array is separated by rows with a unic column, in what way could I pick the section that puts "nombre" in the array?

**Img Array console.log code fila_impuesto=impuestosBD[0]**
[two elements for array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cHyfE.png)

**Code javascript**

```js
impuestos1 = $("#impuestos1-1").val();
impuestosBD = <?php echo(json_encode($impuestos)); ?>;
count_array_impuestosBD = impuestosBD.length;

for (i = 0; i <= count_array_impuestosBD - 1; i++) {
  fila_impuesto = impuestosBD[0][1]; //ERROR result undefined

  console.log(fila_impuesto);

}
```

Comment: Before assign value fila_inpuesto check impuestosBD[0][1] != undefined

Comment: fila_impuestosBD[0][1] gives me undefined

Comment: Because data not available. So before that, you have to put condition and check if is not undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The element you select with `impuestosBD[0]` is an object, and does not contain the property `1`. So `impuestosBD[0][1]` does not exist. Looks like you want `impuestosBD[0].numbre`.

Edit: shouldnt it be `impuestosBD[i]` (i instead of 0)?

Edit 2: You can use `<` without the need of `-1`, instead of `<=` and a `-1`.

```
for(i=0;i<count_array_impuestosBD;i++)
```

Comment: Geeenial amigo muchisimas graaacias!

Comment: Glad that works :) Could you mark it as the answer?